# edit meta tag in your code can someone help how to edit meta description in meta tag?

Tags: user-interface, responsive-design, user-controls, user-experience, user-management

I'm working on site right now (https://karachimoverspackers.com/), and I think I should change meta description or title for better results.

can someone help how to edit meta description in meta tag?
I think I should give it a try and then expect better result.